# Intersection of countably many vector spaces is non empty

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $V_1\supseteq V_2\supseteq V_3\cdots $ be a sequence of infinite dimensional subspaces of a Vector Space $V$. Then I think that the intersection
$\cap_{i\in\mathbb{N}} V_i \neq 0$. But I don't understand how to prove it. I have tried to argue by contradiction but was unable to move forward.

Comment: Isn't $0$ in all of them?

Comment: I guess the OP request is "the intersection has positive dimension"

Comment: I want the intersection to be a nontrivial subspace. Exactly as Exodd says.

Comment: Depending on the subspaces $V_i$, it may or may not be the trivial (zero) subspace. So as a general _theorem_, this is certainly false. But it's a whole different question if you're interested in constructing some examples when it's nontrivial -- you can construct such examples within any infinite dimensional space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually false. Consider the vector space $V$ of polynomials with real coefficients, and define
$$V_i=\{P\in V| P(j)=0,\ j=0,\cdots, i\}.$$
Any polynomial in $\bigcap_{i\in \Bbb N} V_i$ must vanish on all natural numbers, thus the intersection is trivial.